# Numerical Minimization for a function of five variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization, numerical-value

I have the function

```
f[w_,x_,y_, α_,g_]=Sqrt[((w^2 + x^4) (1 + 2 w α^2 + α^4))/(
 2 x^2 w) - α^2 y]*Sqrt[((g w)^2/x^2) + (2 x^2)/w + (2 w (g α - 1 )^2)/x^2]
```

with the restrictions

$$w \geq 1, $$

$$ x>0, $$

$$ y,\alpha, g \in \mathbb{R}.$$

and I appeal to `NMinimize[]` to find a numerical value for the minimum of the function `f[w_,x_,y_, \[Alpha]_,g_]`, that is,

```
NMinimize[{f[w, x, y, α, g], x > 0 && w >= 1}, {w, 
   x, {α, y, g} ∈ Reals}] // Quiet
```

therefore *mathematica* shows the result

```
{2., {w -> 1.78095, x -> 1.33452, \[Alpha] -> -8.73751*10^-9, 
  y -> 0.731324, g -> -2.98148*10^-8}}
```

On the other hand, inquiring in the package help of the software I find that I can specify a non-default method which could give a better solution (with more accuracy), for example with *DifferentialEvolution*; that is,

```
NMinimize[{f[w, x, y, α, g], x > 0 && w >= 1}, {w, 
   x, {α, y, g} ∈ Reals}, 
  Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"] // Quiet
```

giving the result

```
{1.09831, {w -> 1.00016, x -> 0.962037, \[Alpha] -> 0.276323, 
  y -> 11.3393, g -> -0.0477925}}
```

Therefore, I have the question:

**What is the best method (with mathematica) to obtain the most accurate value for the real minimum of the function?**

P.D.
I am a novice with the use of NMinimize comand

Comment: The short answer: it depends on the problem. The (very) long answer: [Constrained Optimization Tutorial,, points 4 and 5](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationOverview.html).Furthermore, using `Quiet` can be dangerous; you should at least see the warnings in order to evaluate them and the quality of the results.

Answer (score 2):

Its clear that the product of two square roots is nonnegative over the reals. Its zero value is not attained as

```
FindInstance[((g w)^2/x^2) + (2 x^2)/w + (2 w (g \[Alpha] - 1)^2)/
x^2 == 0 && w >= 1 &&  x >= 0 && ((w^2 + x^4) (1 + 
2 w \[Alpha]^2 + \[Alpha]^4))/(2 x^2 w) - \[Alpha]^2 y >=  0, {w,x,\[Alpha],y,g}, Reals]
```

> `{}`

shows. However, an arbitrary small positive value is reached. For example,

```
FindInstance[Sqrt[((w^2 + x^4) (1 + 
2 w \[Alpha]^2 + \[Alpha]^4))/(2 x^2 w) - \[Alpha]^2 y]*
Sqrt[((g w)^2/x^2) + (2 x^2)/w + (2 w (g \[Alpha] - 1)^2)/x^2] == 
0.0000001 && w >= 1 && x > 0, {w, x, \[Alpha], y, g}, Reals]
```

> `{w -> 1., x -> 0.4375,  \[Alpha] -> -1., y ->  10.831792091836736,  g -> 0}`

Addition. A more careful analysis

```
FindInstance[w >= 1 && x >= 0 && ((w^2 + x^4) (1 + 2 w \[Alpha]^2 +
\[Alpha]^4))/(2 x^2 w) - \[Alpha]^2 y == 0, {w, x, \[Alpha], y, g}, Reals]
```

> `{{w -> 1, x -> 1, \[Alpha] -> 1, y -> 4, g -> 99/5}}`

demonsrates that  zero nevertheless  is reached. The same command wth the `5` option results in

> `{{w -> 338, x -> 67, \[Alpha] -> -87,  y -> 632344297964095/11484307458, g -> -(1/2)}, {w -> 383,  x -> 73, \[Alpha] -> 11, y -> 1531835123520/246961847,  g -> -(189/10)}, {w -> 114, x -> 50, \[Alpha] -> -53,  y -> 6678650689783/200141250, g -> -(69/10)}, {w -> 423,  x -> 48, \[Alpha] -> -27, y -> 4861448945/1096416,  g -> -(69/10)}, {w -> 29, x -> 34, \[Alpha] -> 62,  y -> 20056704267153/257732512, g -> -(82/5)}}`

Comment: Of course, something like `10*I*10*I` is not taken into consideration because of the domains of the square roots over the reals

Comment: `NMinimize` with the `Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 1}` option gives `{0.17636, {w -> 1.58662, x -> 1.04772, \[Alpha] -> 0.842049, 
  y -> 5.64141, g -> 0.736988}}`.